# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, webapi

I got 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db' error while doing Restfull api using MongoDB with nojs. Can you help to solve the error?

```
DOCKER-COMPOSE.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    restart: always
    environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - '27017:27017' 
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  mongo-data:
```

I have not tried what has been done to solve this error before, but it did not happen

Comment: What command exactly are you running that produces the error?  (`npm run dev` on the host system, for example, won't be able to see a `db` host name.)  Are you sure the database is actually starting up?  (If it exits then you can see an error message like this.)  Is there any other punctuation or other hints in the error message?

Comment: i'm running this command : node app.js

Comment: If you're running that from outside a container then you can't see the host names inside the Docker network.  Try configuring your application to talk to the published `ports:` instead, `localhost:27017` if the Node application and MongoDB container are on the same system.

Comment: what do you think I should change in this code

Comment: The Compose file seems fine from what I can tell.